# Moving folders with the files with exceptions

Tags: powershell, exception, move

I'm trying to move data from the "file" folder and exclude the `Users` folder. but in the end, the exception does not work.

```
Move-Item -Path $env:SystemDrive\$env:computername\File\* -exclude $env:SystemDrive\$env:computername\File\Users\*  -Destination $env:SystemDrive\UserOld\
```

It is necessary to transfer the data and exclude the `Users` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using `move-item` in order to move folders while excluding a single folder and it doesnt seem like you need to include the entire path in the exclude.
I tried this:

```
Move-Item -Path C:\Users\D.Baier\Desktop\testenvironment\Source -Exclude mit-1 -Destination C:\Users\D.Baier\Desktop\testenvironment\Target\
```

and it seemed to work perfectly, just threw an error which seems to be [a known issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2385), at least as far as I understand it. 
The error was the following btw:

```
Move-Item : The Element cannot be moved, since the Element, located at "C:\Users\D.Baier\Desktop\testenvironment\Source\mit-1" does not exist.
In Line:1 Charakter:1
+ Move-Item -Path C:\Users\D.Baier\Desktop\testenvironment\Source \* -Exclu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Hope that was helpful!

Edit: Sorry, my PC is set to German. I translated the error message as well as I can, however I doubt it is the exact same one one would get if you were to run this code on an English machine. I also apologize for any spelling mistakes I may have made.

Comment: SO is an English only site, please update your answer to be in English as the error messages you provided is currently un-readable :)

Comment: Done - hope that clarifies things :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to touch on is how you're creating your paths. You shouldn't create them the way you are, you should instead use the [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) command :)

This is how I might approach your current problem:

```
#Creating path to source folder
$source = Join-Path -Path "$env:SystemDrive\$env:COMPUTERNAME" -ChildPath "File"
#Creating path to destination folder
$destination = Join-Path -Path $env:SystemDrive -ChildPath "UserOld"

#Looping through all the folders in the source
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object{

    #Only moving the folder if the name isn't "Users"
    if ($_.Name -ne "Users"){
        Write-Host "Currently Moving: $_.Name"
        #Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination
    }

}
```

Let me know how you get on, I've left the actual moving part commented out as I would encourage you to do more testing :)

Answer (score 0):

carelessness

```
#Creating path to source folder
$source = Join-Path -Path "$env:SystemDrive\$env:COMPUTERNAME" -ChildPath "\File\C$\"
#Creating path to destination folder
$destination = Join-Path -Path $env:SystemDrive -ChildPath "UserOld"
$h = "Users", "Windows", "ProgramData"
#Looping through all the folders in the source
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | ForEach-Object{

    #Only moving the folder if the name isn't "Users"
    if ($_.Name -ne "$h"){
        Write-Host "Currently Moving: $_.Name"
        }
Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Exclude $h -Destination $destination
}
```

This option moves the Users folder without content.
For this reason, the combined answers.

```
#Creating path to destination folder
$destination = Join-Path -Path $env:SystemDrive -ChildPath "UserOld"
    #Move with the exception
        Move-Item -Path $env:SystemDrive\$env:computername\USMT\File\C$\* -Exclude "Users", "Windows","ProgramData","Program Files","Program Files (x86)" -Destination $destination
```